# AWS-Glue job: pyWriteDynamicFrame validation error "failed to satisfy constraint"

Tags: aws-glue

What is the meaning of the following error? I get it when trying to write to a data sink

```
An error occurred while calling o114.pyWriteDynamicFrame. 1 validation error detected: Value at 'partitions.1.member.storageDescriptor.serdeInfo.serializationLibrary' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length greater than or equal to 1 (Service: AWSGlue; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: bec160ab-8ea2-48ed-b6fc-ea3da7a4c6d4; Proxy: null)
```

The code section is

```py
    sink = glueContext.getSink(
        path=f"s3://{bucket}/data",
        connection_type="s3",
        updateBehavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
        partitionKeys=['year', 'month', 'day'],
        compression="snappy",
        enableUpdateCatalog=True,
    )
    sink.setCatalogInfo(
        catalogDatabase=database, catalogTableName=table
    )
    sink.setFormat("glueparquet")

    sink.writeFrame(my_dataframe.coalesce(1))
```

I tried adding the corresponding columns to the table as follows, but it didn't solve the problem.

```js
      let partitionKeys = [{
        name: 'year', type: 'string'
      },
      {
        name: 'month', type: 'string'
      },
      {
        name: 'day', type: 'string'
      },]

      const entityTable = new glue.CfnTable(this, entity_name + 'Table', {
        catalogId: accountId,
        databaseName: utcDatabase.ref,
        tableInput: {
          description: entity.description !== undefined ? entity.description : '',
          name: glueTableName,
          partitionKeys: partitionKeys,
          storageDescriptor: {
            columns: [...entity_columns, ...partitionKeys],
          },
        },
      });
```

When I try to use a non-existing table as a sink, then a new table is correctly created.